# Ticket to Ride United Kingdom Map Collection competing technology cards clarification

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom

There are two technology cards in this set which either scores you points or lose:
Risky Contracts for the most completed Tickets 
and 
Equalising Beam for the longest Route.

The rules are very short for each:

"At the end of the game, score 20 if you have the most completed Tickets. If not, lose 20 points."

"At the end of the game, score 15 points if you have the longest Route. If not lose 15 points."

What happens if multiple players have the most or longest? What is the rule for a draw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for longest path say, "In the case of a tie for the longest
path, all tied players score the 10 point bonus."

So all players whom have the longest path or most tickets would qualify to score the bonus from the permits if they had them.

Comment: as further evidence to this, in that 'ties are friendly' this has been confirmed on Days of Wonder Forums here https://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?goto=361366#msg_361366

Comment: @StartPlayer : Since a Risky Contracts card must be purchased (before the train cards are reshuffled), in order to get the bonus, and there is only one (1) such card, only one player can get the bonus. The same is true of the Equalising Beam card.

Comment: @RobertMiller I understand that there is only one such card.  The clarification is that is player A has joint longest route with another player and the one Equalising Beam card that they still get the bonus points (and just them) even if they longest route is tied with another player.